# Prove $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n[\int_a^b f(x)dx-\sum_{k=1}^n f(a+k\frac{b-a}{n})\frac{b-a}{n}]=-\frac{1}{2}(b-a)\int_a^b f'(x)dx$

Tags: calculus

Assume $f(x)$ is a continuous function on $[a,b]$, and its first-order derivative $f'(x)$ is also continuous on $[a,b]$, prove the identity:

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n\left[\int_a^b f(x)dx-\sum_{k=1}^n f\left(a+k\frac{b-a}{n}\right)\frac{b-a}{n}\right]=-\frac{1}{2}(b-a)\int_a^b f'(x)\,dx$$

I came across this problem in a generalized form question of my problem sets.

My idea is to use the definition of integral, namely expanding $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx$ into $\lim\limits_{m\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^m f(\varepsilon_k)\frac{b-a}{m}$, in which $\varepsilon_k\in[a+(k-1)\frac{b-a}{m},a+k\frac{b-a}{m}]$.

But the problem is that there are two limit processes, namely $n\to\infty$ and $m\to\infty$, which are supposed to be separate. Thus, it is not easy to combine $\sum_{k=1}^m f(\varepsilon_k)\frac{b-a}{m}$ with $\sum_{k=1}^n f(a+k\frac{b-a}{n})\frac{b-a}{n}$. Even though somehow these two processes are integrated into one process, I get totally different result of this limit with Lagrange's Mean Value Theorem, by letting $\varepsilon_k=a+(k-\theta)\frac{b-a}{n}$, in which $\theta\in[0,1]$, and choosing $\theta$ differently.

There must be something wrong with my method, but I can not see it(probably it is not legal to integrate these two limit processes?).

I will really appreciate it if you can help to prove this identity or point out the problem in my method!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right path, but using one partition depending on $n$ suffices. The main trick is to break the interval of integration in pieces of equal length and then compare integrals over small segments against their Riemann approximation.

Maybe this will help you complete your task

\begin{aligned}
n\Big(\int_a^b f(x)dx -\sum_{k=1}^n f\big(a+k\tfrac{b-a}{n}\big)\tfrac{b-a}{n}\Big)&=n\Big(\sum^n_{k=1}\int^{a+k\tfrac{(b-a)}{n}}_{a+(k-1)\tfrac{(b-a)}{n}} f(x)-f\big(a+k\tfrac{b-a}{n}\big)\,dx\Big)\\
&=n\Big(\sum^n_{k=1}\int^{k\tfrac{(b-a)}{n}}_{(k-1)\tfrac{(b-a)}{n}} f(a+u)-f\big(a+k\tfrac{b-a}{n}\big)\,du\Big)\\
&=(b-a)\Big(\sum^n_{k=1}\int^{k}_{k-1} f\big(a+t\tfrac{b-a}{n}\big)-f\big(a+k\tfrac{b-a}{n}\big)\,dt\Big)
\end{aligned}

Here we have used changes of variables $u=x-a$, followed by  $t=\frac{n}{b-a}u$

Using the mean value theorem one obtains

\begin{aligned}
(b-a)\Big(\sum^n_{k=1}\int^{k}_{k-1} f\big(a+t\tfrac{b-a}{n}\big) &-f\big(a+k\tfrac{b-a}{n}\big)\,dt\Big)\\
&=(b-a)\sum^n_{k=1}\int^{k}_{k-1} f'\big(a+(t\theta_t+(1-\theta_t)k)\tfrac{b-a}{n}\big)(t-k)\tfrac{b-a}{n}\,dt\\
&\approx (b-a)\sum^n_{k=1}f'\big(a+k\tfrac{b-a}{n}\big)\Big(\int^{k}_{k-1} (t-k)\,dt\Big)\tfrac{b-a}{n}\\
&=-\frac{b-a}{2}\sum^n_{k=1}f'\big(a+k\tfrac{b-a}{n}\big)\tfrac{b-a}{n}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty} -\frac{b-a}{2}\int^b_af'
\end{aligned}

where $0<\theta_t<1$ depends on $t$. The approximation need some justification (the uniform continuity of $f'$ will do).

Comment: Really thanks! The first equation is a bit hard for me to come up with independently now. But from this, I have got some experience and learned something!

Comment: It does take some experience. The trick here is to notice that each term of the Riemann sum for an integral $\int^b_ag$ is also an approximation of the value of the integral of $g$ over a small piece of the interval. That is $g(a+k\frac{b-a}{n})\frac{b-a}{n}\approx \int^{a+k\tfrac{b-a}{n}}_{a+(k-1)\frac{b-a}{n}}g$

Comment: In the last approximation, is first mean value theorem for definite integral an alternative solution? Namely, $\int_{k-1}^{k}f'(a+(t\theta_t+(1-\theta_t)k)\frac{b-a}{n})(t-k)dt=f'(\varepsilon_k)\int_{k-1}^{k}(t-k)dt$, in which $\varepsilon_k\in [a+(k-1)\frac{b-a}{n},a+k\frac{b-a}{n}]$.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot! I understand the uniform continuity works, but can't first mean value theorem for definite integral be another approach to evaluate this integral?

Comment: Yes you could use the mean value for intgegrals. In any case, you have to then compare the value of $f'(intermediate\,\,point)$ with $f'(a+k\tfrac{b-a}{n})$ to obtain a clean Riemann integral (and an $\epsilon$ terms for the error. Either way, you get the same result.